# Dagger 2.11 - how to make Activity and Fragment share common values?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

I am currently learning Dagger 2 on Android and I would like to inject the Activity's injection into the Fragment, but I do not know how.

This a working setup, that shows the values being injected into the fragment and the activity.

Sorry for the wall of code, I simplified my code so that it only contains the relevant parts.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, AppModule::class, BuildersModule::class))
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun setApplication(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent

    }

    fun apiService() : ApiService

    fun inject(app: App)
}

@Module(subcomponents = arrayOf(MainActivitySubComponent::class, MainFragmentSubComponent::class))
class AppModule

@Module
abstract class BuildersModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(MainActivity::class)
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(builder: MainActivitySubComponent.Builder): AndroidInjector.Factory<out Activity>


    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @dagger.android.support.FragmentKey(MainFragment::class)
    abstract fun bindMainFragment(builder: MainFragmentSubComponent.Builder): AndroidInjector.Factory<out Fragment>

}
```

The `AppComponent` is created inside the Application:

```
class App : Application(), HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    var activityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .setApplication(this)
                .build()
                .inject(this)
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity>? {
        return activityInjector
    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = arrayOf(MainActivityModule::class))
interface MainActivitySubComponent : AndroidInjector<MainActivity> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity>()
}

@Module
class MainActivityModule {

    @Provides
    fun providePresenter(mainView: MainView, apiService: ApiService): MainPresenter
            = MainPresenterImpl(mainView, apiService)

}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mainPresenter: MainPresenter

    @Inject
    lateinit var fragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, MainFragment())
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss()
        }
    }

    override fun supportFragmentInjector() = fragmentInjector

}
```

MainFragment:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = arrayOf(MainFragmentModule::class))
interface MainFragmentSubComponent : AndroidInjector<MainFragment> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<MainFragment>()
}

@Module
class MainFragmentModule {

    @Provides
    fun providePresenter(mainView: MainView, apiService: ApiService): MainPresenter
            = MainPresenterImpl(mainView, apiService)
}

class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mainPresenter: MainPresenter

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
        super.onAttach(context)
    }
}
```

So I've found out how activity and fragment can use the same `ApiService` class.
I'd like to inject the same instance of `MainPresenter` in both `MainActivity` and `MainFragment`.

How could I gain access to the Activity's injected `MainPresenter` without changing the code in `MainFragment`? Basically, I don't want the `MainFragment` to know anything about how it is injected.

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed because I thought I was onto something but it's a bit more complicated than I thought. I don't see how to create subscoped subcomponent for activity / fragment with AndroidInjection.

Comment: Maybe the answer is in https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/di